# How to bind JSON object to inputs using Vue

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following json object :

```
{
"chart": {
   "type": "linerdfgdgdfgf",
   "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
   "borderColor": "#000",
   "borderWidth": 0,
   "height": 300,
   "inverted": false,
   "plotBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
   "plotBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
   "plotBorderWidth": 1,
   "style": {
     "fontFamily": "Open Sans"
    }
  }
 }
```

How to map these object values to input boxes?

I use this function inside method function.

```
getmyEditor: function(){

      chartType: this.options.chart.type;
      this.backgroundColor = this.options.chart.backgroundColor;
      this.borderColor = this.options.chart.borderColor;
      this.borderWidth = this.options.chart.borderWidth;
      this.height = this.options.chart.height;
      this.inverted = this.options.chart.inverted;
      this.plotBackgroundColor = this.options.chart.plotBackgroundColor;
 }
```

Comment: you want to change the style or show those values to input?